# C# Error: “Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.” just in on pc

Tags: c#, sql

This is my code:

```
  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
```

This program is working on *all other pc's* except for the one I've got, where I'm getting this error:

```
  System.InvalidOperationException: Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.GetConnection3(DbDataAdapter adapter, IDbCommand command, String method)
    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
    at service_managment.V.Fill_data_set(String query)
    at service_managment.V.get_first_of_tabel(String query)
    at service_managment.login.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    at service_managment.login.tbx_password_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you initialize `conn` before calling `new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn)`?

Comment: Can you Please post your full code for us to understand the problem?

Comment: you're not assigning *connection* to your *command* object. post you full code to get pointed at the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you define a `SqlConnection` like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
```

But you didn't set it's [`ConnectionString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property.Make sure you set your `ConnectionString` correctly then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning *connection* to your *command* object will solve the problem. Make sure you have assigned connection to command. for example

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString");
cmd.connection = conn;
```

Must solve the problem. or if you have defined your command object as:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandtext, conn);
```

Then in this case, your **conn** object is not initialized. Make sure to initialize it first, as:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString");
```

Answer (score 0):

If same code is working on different machines but not on your machine, then there are following posibilities:

1. You don't have server access.
2. Probably your connectionstring accessing a local database file which you don't have on your machine.
3. You forgot to set connectionstring for your connection object.
4. You forgot to set connection for your command object.
5. You haven't initialized a connection object before filling the data adapter.

Varify your code and try to find the issue.